# How to link a shared library to a makefile

Tags: makefile

Hello everyone I have the following makefile:

```
LHAPDFldflag = -L "/home/user/local/lib -lLHAPDF"
LHAPDFincdir = -I "/home/user/local/include/"


demo: demo.o vegas.o ranlxd.o
    g++ -o demo demo.o vegas.o ranlxd.o -lgfortran ${LHAPDFldflag}
    
demo.o: demo.cpp
     g++ ${LHAPDFincdir} -c demo.cpp 
     
vegas.o: vegas.F
    gfortran -c vegas.F

ranlxd.o: ranlxd.c
    gcc -c ranlxd.c

clean:
    rm -f  vegas.o ranlxd.o

distclean: clean
    rm -f demo
```

In my demo.cpp I call a function from the library. After trying 'make' I receive the following error:

```
g++ -o demo demo.o vegas.o ranlxd.o -lgfortran -L "/home/user/local/lib -lLHAPDF"
/usr/bin/ld: demo.o: in function `main':
demo.cpp:(.text+0x13ca): undefined reference to `LHAPDF::initPDFSet(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:6: demo] Error 1
```

As far as I know an undefined reference error originates from a problem in the linker stage which is also indicated by the last line of the error. But I am wondering that in the fourth line of the error code it seems to know the function that I want to call. Is the problem here really in the linking? I don´t see whats wrong with the line 6 of my makefile which is refered to in the error code. Could there be another explanation? I highly appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: I've never seen the linker called like that. I presume the library is in `/home/user/local/lib`. I suggest you try `LHAPDFldflag = -L/home/user/local/lib -lLHAPDF`, and if that doesn't work, tell us how you build the library.

Comment: `-L` takes a path only, you passed a whole string, @Beta's suggestion should work